# Create serial mail on linux commandline

Tags: linux, email, command-line

I would like to generate serial emails on the linux commandline. Assume I have a file indicating mail address, subject and message text in columns on separate lines for each recipient. I.e.

```
recipient1@mail.com subject1 text1
recipient2@mail.com subject2 text2
...
```

The script should use standard commands as I intend to send it to colleagues who should create some emails for me.
The loop over the lines could be with xargs ... Can I use the commandline tool `mail`?

It is important that the mails are not send immediately. Ideally it creates files for import in the users preferred mail client. So that senders can check the mails before they submit.
I also would like to be able to add attachments to the Mails.

I tried e.g.

```
function mail_kmail {
    kmail -s "$2" --body "$3" --attach "$4" --composer "$1" 
}

function mail_thunderbird {
    thunderbird -compose "to='$1',subject='$2',body='$3',attachment='$4'" 
}
```

and reading the input data from file with

```
while read recipient subject body attach $file
do
  mail_kmail "$recipient" "$subject" "$body" "$attach";
done
```

but this will work only if my colleagues installed and set up either of these mail clients.

I found this (closed) related question:
[How can i send automated email in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304717/how-can-i-send-automated-email-in-linux) .

Comment: see the reason why it was closed. what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutt to send the emails, here is an example:

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

Since it's hard to know what you are trying to achieving here, you can even create a configuration file to be used, but you'll to investigate more or give more details about your use case.